# Moving the player without touching it

Tags: java, android

I am working on a simple 2D infinite runner game. I am trying to get the player to move in any direction without needing to touch the player specifically. I want the game to find where the user touches and then allow the user to control the player from there. At the moment the player moves but only when the user is touching the player directly which makes it difficult for the user to see the actual player when playing and trying to dodge obstacles.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
public boolean recieveTouch(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            int action = event.getAction();
            int x = (int) event.getX();  // or getRawX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();
            int h2 = bitmap2.getHeight();
            int w2 = bitmap2.getWidth();
            float xRatio2 = (Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH / 2)-( w2 / 2);
            float yRatio2 = (Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2)-( h2 / 2) + (Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH/4 + (Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH/6)- Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/10);

            int h55 = bitmap55.getHeight();
            int w55 = bitmap55.getWidth();
            int h66 = bitmap66.getHeight();
            int w66 = bitmap66.getWidth();
            float xRatio55 = ((Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH / 4)-( w55 / 4));
            float yRatio55 = (((Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) + (h55 / 2)) + (Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/6));
            float xRatio66 = ((Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH / 2)+( w66 / 4) + (Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/24));
            float yRatio66 = (((Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) + (h66 / 2)) + (Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/6));
            //help
            int h5 = bitmap4.getHeight();
            int w5 = bitmap4.getWidth();
            float xRatio5 = ((Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH / 4) - (w5 / 1));
            float yRatio5 = (((Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 8) - (h5 / 1)));

            long pressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                if (!gameOver && player.getRectangle().contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()))
                    movingPlayer = true;
                if (gameOver && System.currentTimeMillis() - gameOverTime >= 0) {
                    if (x >= xRatio2 && x < (xRatio2 + bitmap2.getWidth())
                            && y >= yRatio2 && y < (yRatio2 + bitmap2.getHeight())) {
                        if (GamePanel.Ad1 == 1) {
                            MainActivity.click.start();
                            MainActivity.mAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(mActivityRef.get());
                            loadAd();
                            MainActivity.mAd.show();
                            //Appodeal.show(mActivityRef.get(), Appodeal.REWARDED_VIDEO);
                        }
                    }
                    if (x >= xRatio55 && x < (xRatio55 + bitmap55.getWidth())
                            && y >= yRatio55 && y < (yRatio55 + bitmap55.getHeight())) {
                        MainActivity.click.start();
                        reset();
                        gameOver = false;
                        orientationData.newGame();
                    }
                    if (x >= xRatio66 && x < (xRatio66 + bitmap66.getWidth())
                            && y >= yRatio66 && y < (yRatio66 + bitmap66.getHeight())) {
                        MainActivity.click.start();
                        SceneManager.ACTIVE_SCENE = 4;
                        MainActivity.mInterstitialAd.loadAd((new AdRequest.Builder().build()));
                        MainActivity.mInterstitialAd.show();
                        //Appodeal.show(mActivityRef.get(), Appodeal.INTERSTITIAL);

                        if (GamePanel.YelowBird == 4) {
                            GamePanel.YelowBird = 2;
                            GamePanel.RedBird = 1;
                        }


                        reset();
                        gameOver = false;

                    }
                    if (x >= xRatio5 && x < (xRatio5 + bitmap4.getWidth())
                            && y >= yRatio5 && y < (yRatio5 + bitmap4.getHeight())) {
                        if (GamePanel.Help == 0) {
                            GamePanel.Help = 1;
                            if (GamePanel.Help == 1) {
                                MainActivity.click.start();
                                orientationData.register();
                            }

                        } else if (GamePanel.Help == 1) {
                            GamePanel.Help = 0;
                            if (GamePanel.Help == 0) {
                                MainActivity.click.start();
                                orientationData.pause();
                            }
                        }



                } return true;
            }

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (GamePanel.NinjaBird == 4) {
                if (!gameOver)
                    playerPoint.set((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
            } else {
                if (!gameOver && movingPlayer)
                    playerPoint.set((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            movingPlayer = false;
            break;

    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone else wants to do a similar thing:
i changed the following line
from this:

if (!gameOver && movingPlayer)
                    playerPoint.set((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
to this:

if (!gameOver && movingPlayer)
                    playerPoint.set((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()+200);

so you move the player by touching 200 pixels under it.